# Alternar dos valores en array JS

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Consideremos el siguiente problema relacionado a algoritmos con JS.

Dado un arreglo aleatorio con valores entre 0 y 1:

- Alternar (flip) cada valor del arreglo, de tal forma que la secuencia se vaya alternando, entre [0 y 1] o viceversa.
- Al final, se debe computar el número de veces que se realizó la operación de alternar (flip) y regresar este valor como resultado.

Esta es una pregunta de exámen para vacantes de Web Developer.

Adjunto algunos casos para pruebas:

- randomArray = [1,0,1,0,1,1]; r : 1
- randomArray = [0,1,0]; r : 0
- randomArray = [1,1,0,1,1]; r: 3
- randomArray = [0,1,1,0]; r :2

Comment: No veo una pregunta aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function flip(array) {
  let flip = 0;

  for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
      // negar el valor actual si es igual al anterior
      array[i] = ~array[i] & 0b1;
      flip++;
    }
  }

  return flip;
}

console.log(flip([0, 1, 1, 0]));
```

Comment: He notado el uso de indices dinámicos en la resolución de algoritmos, se requiere cierto nivel. Por otro lado, no había visto el uso del operador tilde, es bueno saber esto, saludos @Lobos.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let randomArray = [1,1,0,1,1];// r: 3
 //let randomArray = [0,1,1,0]; r :2
 let counter = 0;
 let anterior = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++){
      if(i > 0){
          if(randomArray[i] == 0){
              if(anterior == 0){
                  counter = counter + 1;
                  randomArray[i] = 1;
              } 
          } else {
              if(anterior == 1) {
                  counter = counter + 1;
                  randomArray[i] = 0;
              }
          }
          anterior = randomArray[i];
      } else {
          //primera vez
          anterior = randomArray[i];
    }
}
    
console.log(counter);
```